# ipvs based lvs system, is there going to be very high load on the front server?

Tags: load-balancing, traffic, lvs

there are 4 servers with the same hardware configurations, and a ipvs based lvs system is constructed on these 4 servers using NAT.
my question is simple: will there be very high load on the front server which was in charge of transferring traffic to the whole lvs system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear: You're setting up a single server to act as load balancer, using [Linux' IPVS kernel module](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html)? And the load balancer has around 4 or so backend HTTP servers behind it?

No, that shouldn't be a problem at all. IPVS does load balancing at the TCP/IP level, so it's capable of very high packet rates on modest servers. Handling 4 backend servers should be no problem.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. 4 backend server structure is no problem, but since i use NAT, the front server could be a bottleneck for that it must handle both the requests and the responses, as the lvs document mentioned ;-)

Comment: @xpu: I agree, the NAT'ing means the load balancer has som additional work to do. Even so, with just 4 backend servers, there should be no capacity problems on the load balancer. Of course, you're not providing any data, so I'm using my best guess for "normal" HTTP traffic -- if you're dealing with extremely high connection rates and very small objects, then things may be different. I doubt it, but you should always get measurements.

Comment: yeap, it should be enough for normal traffice, and should be more ok than nginx